# My python script does not print table from html

Tags: python, html-table

I am trying to get table data from below code but surprisingly the script shows a "none" output for table, though I could clearly see it in my HTML doc.
Look forward for help..[image: The below image shows the "inspect view of the document"]]

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = 'http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/78.0.3904.108'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
res = urlopen(req)
rawpage = res.read()
page = rawpage.replace("<!-->", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"table workitems-table mt-2"})
print (table)
```

Also here comes the code with Selenium Script as suggested:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\rugupta\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.7\\chromedriver.exe') 

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('root').click() #click on search button to fetch list of bus schedule

time.sleep(10) #depends on how long it will take to go to next page after button click

for i in range(1,50):
    url = "http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp".format(pagenum = i)

text_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/table")
for h3Tag in text_field:
    print(h3Tag.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The page wasn't fully loaded when you use Request. you can debug by printing `res`.
It seems the page is using javascript to load the table.

You should use selenium, load the page with driver (eg: chromedriver, Firefoxdriver). Sleep a while until the page is loaded (you define it, it take quite a bit to load fully). Then get the table using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver) 

driver.get(url)
# I dont understand what's the purpose when clicking that button
time.sleep(100) 

text_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/table')
print (text_field[0].text)
```

You code worked fine with a bit of modifying, this will print all the text from the table. You should learn to debug and change it to get what you want.

This is my output running above scripts

[image: This is my output running above scripts]

Comment: Ok, So here is my Selenium Script:

Comment: Hi Hung, As suggested by you, I have put it in the code window :) but not working, am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi Hung, thanks again for your reply though the script suggested by you only throws table headings..am also trying to debug it..attached an output image attached for your reference:

Comment: Please recheck if you run it properly, I inserted my output @Zygote

Comment: ah that's what I am looking for in EXACT! but my white IDLE still throws attached error!!am stuck but checking...

Comment: You didnt wait long enough @Zygote. It is 100s in my code. That's why. You can wait until the web load by yourself, you dont need to use sleep while running scripts

Comment: I waited for 10s, and the output is exactly the same as yours @Zygote

Comment: Hey Hung, thanks so much for that direction...yes am seeing the output now. I flagged your answer as useful. though I do not have enough repute to vote! (: Now am trying to save the data in data frame and export it in CSV!

Comment: I flagged it as an accepted answer: hope it goes good! I also should say clearly that flag had other comments as well like "rude", "unuseful" but I have clearly selected "others" and notified this answer as useful and acceptable.!

Comment: Thanks again Hung!